# XSS Encoding in JavaScript Context

Tags: xss

I am taking a user input in C++ code and passing it into a JS function. It's causing XSS. The code below is a simplified version of the problem. If you run it, it will show an alert. Will HTML encoding fix it or is there any other encoding for this scenario?

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">

function f1(id1, id2, flag){}

<!-- alert(1) is user input that was passed into this function  -->
f1(768, alert(1), true);

</SCRIPT>
</head><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are generating JavaScript code. You can't use html entities to encode or escape dangerous characters. If you were trying to encode the `()` characters you are likely to generate JS syntax errors.

Don't try to detect function calls by looking for `(…)`. This simple hack will bypass your check:

```js
alert`"gotcha!"`
```

You *could* quote `alert(1)` so that it becomes a string `"alert(1)"` but then an attacker could simply submit this as input: `", alert(1), "` which would produce something like that: (and still execute code)

```js
f1(768, "", alert(1), "", true);
```

In cases like yours I would look into creating a sandboxed environment where code can run without privileged access.